# How can I create a UITableView loading data style like the Facebook App style?

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview

I would like to create a loading data style in my UITableView like the Facebook App.
Scrolling down the TableView data is reloaded with a spin wheel in the first row.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many sample projects that show how to do "pull to refresh". Here's just one: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egotableviewpullrefresh

Answer (score 1):

I like SVPullToRefresh - https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh . It's a little cleaner than the EGO project and has infinite scrolling builtin as well.